# To describe the picture

Tags: sentence-meaning

### Can *A is in two boxes* describe both 1 and 2?

[image]

Comment: Diagram 2 shows only one A in a box. You have 1. An A in a box, inside another box, 2. An A in a box above an empty box.

Comment: This is probably related to the previous questions... I don't think the answer is English specific.  I suspect there is some point to these questions, but I'm not sure what it really is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

In drawing 1, the A is inside two boxes. The A is in a box and that box is in another box.

In drawing 2 the A is inside one of the two boxes. The other box is empty.